# Ethereum ICO metadata

Tags: ico

When an ICO contract is created, is the meta-data of the computer used to create the ICO linked to the contract?

If I feel a token/ICO coin is a scam, how would I go about harvesting meta-data to build a case?

Answer (score 1):

> When an ICO contract is created, is the meta-data of the computer used
>   to create the ICO linked to the contract?

No Metadata is ever present in the smart contract relating to someone's PC or IP.
The only thing that can link you/or owner identity to public is the address that created the smart contract. If you use address "X" to create the smart contract and you had earlier used that address on some exchanges or posted it on public forum then you are likely to be traced. But generally if you have used a new address and received eth from a mixer to make the contract then you are highly likely to be anonymous.

> If I feel a token/ICO coin is a scam, how would I go about harvesting
>   meta-data to build a case?

These days ICO has become a quick money tradition.
I remember few years back if a ICO launches then they were usually able to raise a plethora of funds, but these days every 2 of the five crypto investor with some coding knowledge is making a new project to raise money and 90% of the ICOs are just snatching candy from innocent investors.

There is nothing you can do except keeping your eye open and investing only in projects that you have confidence.

**Extra:** these days Forking is a new way to make money, days are gone for ICO as they now requires a lot of money to advertise themselves and even investors/ crypto community has became smart.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the code for an ICO is published to GitHub, although there's no guarantee that this is the same code that's used to create the ICO contract. You can also see the transaction that created the contract on e.g. EthereumScan.

However, the token might be perfect, but it doesn't guarantee that the team will use the collected money responsively. If they can withdraw money, nothing prevents them from taking them and just run away.